# Redirect maven test logging to eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit4, surefire

I run my tests using maven surefire plugin. When I need to debug the code, I use
`mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test`  to redirect to eclipse debugger.

This works well, but the log statements are not redirected to eclipse console. 
Is there anyway we can redirect `log and System.out` statements to eclipse console view.

I tried setting `useFile=false and maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile=false` properties. These options don't seem work.

Comment: Why are you calling the command line if you like to run unit tests in Eclipse? Just start the unit test from Eclipse and the logging output will be put into eclipse console.

Comment: Eclipse uses M2E plugin which is different from actual maven installation. I have multiple projects in my workspace, so M2E plugin doesn't work consistently for build and test cases. However, build and test cases work fine in command line. Seems like lot of people face issues with M2E plugin and the recommended approach is to with command line.

Comment: @NareshVavilala You can define an external Maven via Window → Preferences → Maven → Installations in Eclipse.

Comment: @NareshVavilala My previous comment was just meant to address your first comment not your original question.

If I run a _Run Configuration_ of type _Maven Build_ with _test_ goal and a Parameter _maven.surefire.debug=true_ and if I connect to that with a _Debug Configuration_ of type _Remote Java Application_ both `System.out.println(...)` and `Logger.info(...)` are printed to my Eclipse's Console view.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes. log statements do get printed if I run the maven build in eclipse. but i face many other issues with eclipse build and tests, so i am looking for a way to redirect logging from maven command line to eclipse console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any commandline process from eclipse by adding it as an External Tool.

First, open the external tools dialog:

[image: External Tools Configurations...]

Then, add a new tool...

[image: Add a new tool]

And configure it to do what you want

[image: Configure it to call maven]

You should then be able to start your test from the external tools menu, and have all of the output directed to the Eclipse console.

[image: Run External Tool from menu]

Comment: I get the error `External tool location specified is not a file` when I add maven location. Also, How can we run individual test cases using this configuration?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What location did you specify for `Location` (where I put `/path/of/maven/installation/mvn`)?  In my case, I used `/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn`, but it might be different on different systems.  On Windows, that would probably look more like `C:\path\to\maven\mvn.exe`, but I'm not exactly sure because I don't have a Windows environment to test it on.

Comment: I am able to get this working. Thanks alot for your answer. I didnt know that we can attach external process to eclipse